# Why is the infinite sum of this trigonometric series =zero yet when I evaluate the finite sum and take the limit $n \to \infty$ it not well defined?

Tags: limits, trigonometric-series

Evaluating the infinite sum of the below trigonometric series yields a result of zero. However, when I calculate the finite sum up to $n$ and subsequently take the limit as $n$ approaches infinity on the result, it seems to be undefined.

We can explicitly perform the infinite sum for $x \in [0 , \frac{\pi}{2})$:

\begin{align*}
- \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m-1} \sin ((2m-1) x) & = - \sum_{m=1}^\infty \cos ((2m-1) (x-\frac{\pi}{2}))
\nonumber \\
& = - \sum_{m=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{i (2m-1)y} + e^{-i (2m-1)y}}{2}  ,  \qquad  y=x-\frac{\pi}{2}
\nonumber \\
& = - \dfrac{e^{i y} \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{i 2m y} + e^{-i y} \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-i 2m y}}{2}
\nonumber \\
& = - \frac{1}{2} \left[ \dfrac{e^{i y}}{1 - e^{i2y}} + \dfrac{e^{-i y}}{1 - e^{-i2y}}
\right]
\nonumber \\
& = - \frac{1}{2} \left[ \dfrac{e^{i y} (1 - e^{-i2y}) + e^{-i y} (1 - e^{i2y})}{|1 - e^{i2y}|^2}
\right]
\nonumber \\
& = 0
\end{align*}

So the series sums to a definite answer of zero.

However: We can explicitly perform the sum for finite $n$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^n (-1)^{m-1} \sin ((2m-1) x) & = - \sum_{m=1}^n \cos ((2m-1) (x-\frac{\pi}{2}))
\nonumber \\
& = - \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{e^{i (2m-1)y} + e^{-i (2m-1)y}}{2}  ,  \qquad  y=x-\frac{\pi}{2}
\nonumber \\
& = - \dfrac{e^{i y} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} e^{i 2m y} + e^{-i y} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} e^{-i 2m y}}{2}
\nonumber \\
& = - \frac{1}{2} \left[ e^{i y} \dfrac{1 - e^{i 2n y}}{1 - e^{i2y}} + e^{-i y} \dfrac{1 - e^{-i 2n y}}{1 - e^{-i2y}}
\right]
\nonumber \\
& = - \frac{1}{2} \left[ \dfrac{(e^{i y} - e^{-i y}) (1 - e^{i 2n y}) + (e^{-i y} - e^{i y}) (1 - e^{-i 2n y})}{4 \sin^2 y}
\right]
\nonumber \\
& = - \dfrac{\sin (2ny)}{2 \sin y}
\nonumber \\
& = (-1)^n \dfrac{\sin (2nx)}{2 \cos x}
\end{align*}

and then take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$. The function $(-1)^n \frac{\sin (2nx)}{2 \cos x}$ exhibits rapid oscillations as $n$ increases, with peak and trough amplitudes having the lower bound:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{2 \cos (\dfrac{\pi}{4n})}
\end{align*}

This lower limit corresponds to the height of the first peak on the interval $[0 , \frac{\pi}{2})$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{4n}$, with subsequent peaks and troughs exhibiting an increasing amplitude as $x$ increases.

So the distance between consecutive peaks tends to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$ while the amplitude remains non-zero and finite. This limit seems undefined, similar to how the limit $ \lim{x \rightarrow 0^+} \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ is undefined. However, when we first performed the infinite sum we got zero. What is the reason for this seeming contradiction?

Comment: I have a very hard time believing your first calculation of zero. Please explain each line in your derivation more.

Comment: Your issue is in the factorization where you remove $e^{iy}$ from the expression. This can be done from your second term, but not your first, so we have a problem.

Comment: By the way, this is the Fourier series for the $\pi$-antiperiodic delta function, and by that, the infinite sum should be zero on the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Hi @Josh B. Do you notice that I initially sum from $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \cdots$ but then in then in a subsequent step I'm summing from $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \cdots$?

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Wang. Here is each line: The first step of converting it from a sum of $(-1)^{m-1} \ sin((2m-1)x)$ to a sum of $\cos((2m-1)(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$ is via trig identities. Used $\cos t =\frac{e^{i t} - e^{-i t}}{2}$. Wrote $\sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{i(2m-1)y} = e^{-iy} \sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{i2my} = e^{+iy} \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{i2my}$. Similarly, for $\sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{-i(2m-1)y}$. ....

Comment: ....Performed the infinite sum $S=\sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{i2my}$ by writing $(1-e^{i2y}) S = 1$. Similarly for $\overline{S}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-i2my}$. Added fractions, and then simplified. Then I substituted in $y = x - \frac{\pi}{2}$ used trig identities to get from the final expression as a function of $x$.

Comment: You used the infinite geometric sum formula when it isn't valid.

Comment: Hi, @coiso. I should have been more careful and wrote $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1-z) S_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1-z^{n+1})$? The limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1-z^{n+1})$ is not defined for $z=e^{i2y}$ so the inifinite geometric sum formula is not valid.

Comment: @ivan44 it is better to edit your question instead of replying a lot of math formulas in comments